# Serverless Lambda Layers in local development with Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to find a reliable way to develop a serverless application that uses Lambda Layer for shared code. Obviously it works in the AWS environment, but when I want to invoke my function with `sls invoke local --function funcName` I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.
Layer code is available in the root project subdirectory and maybe I could add its path, but it will be neither the best solution for scalable development nor elegant.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: you could use the pay version of localstack that has support for  lambda layers https://github.com/localstack/localstack here's an example: https://github.com/localstack/localstack-pro-samples/tree/master/serverless-lambda-layers